# Android GUI: TextView continously updating

Tags: android, user-interface

I have got some problems to understand runOnUiThread(). I want to update the TextView continously but nothing happens. The GUI is still blocked. Could somebody help me?

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        runner();
    }

public void runner (){
    String[] testFiles = GeneralHelper.getPictureFileList();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfeld); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {   
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                text.setText("\n" + GeneralHelper.getPictureFileList()[i]);    
            }


           });
           ...
           // image analysis
}}
```

Comment: Why do you use `runOnUiThread` here ? You are not outside the UIThread/MainThread.

Comment: How long you want to keep UI updating?

Answer (score 0):

The loop has only 2 iterations and it is done so fast that you even can't see changes. You only see result `GeneralHelper.getPictureFileList()[1]` 
And you are inside UiThread so you shouldn't use it. Just:

```
public void runner (){
    String[] testFiles = GeneralHelper.getPictureFileList();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfeld); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
            text.setText("\n" + GeneralHelper.getPictureFileList()[i]);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Every loop takes 5 second for working on each image. I reduced the loop-count (i < 2) for analysing problems.

Comment: 'if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog' (
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) 
you should you AsyncTask. To print debug info just use Log.d("app_tag", "text_to_print");

Comment: My example is not working... the app is working but no information is coming.

Comment: @user2011909 I answered to your questions. If you have another one ask it in new question.

Comment: I do not see any ANR dialog. I only see a black page which will show the text after runner().

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to create your own timer class where you can include runOnUiThread() to update your TextView. That's what I did on a program I wrote where I needed to display the time counting up every second as soon as the user pressed a button.

Comment: Could you give me a sample snippet?